# How to reset Android app on clicking a button?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to programming in Android. What I have is a button which says

> "Do you want to start the game all over again"?

On clicking this button, I want the game to reset so that it returns to its initial state i.e when the user has first opened the game. Should I do this by calling the `onCreate()` method and if so, how?

Comment: just change the state of your application to the initial one. reset all game-related data and refresh views to display "nothing".

Comment: Also you might want to change that button's text to just "Restart"

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't call `onCreate` manually. A pretty easy way to start the current activity from scratch is:

```
finish();
startActivity(MyActivity.class, getIntent());
```

Comment: I thought that you had to start the new activity before calling `finish();`